# Android BatteryManager not reporting correct charging status

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean, battery

I am having a little trouble getting whether a device is charging or not, but **only on some devices.** Namely the Sony Xperia Z and Xperia E.

The battery status always reports the phone as plugged out. I have tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy S4 and a Galaxy S2 and it works correctly on those.

I have a BroadcastReceiver, PowerConnectionReceiver, which is registered in the manifest to receive plugged in/plugged out events. When the receiver gets an intent, it calls another intent to get the current battery status:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    Context context = c.getApplicationContext();


    try{

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

        int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        Toast.makeText(context, "Battery charging " + isCharging , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
```

Can anybody see any obvious flaw in that code? I am stumped. Both the Sony Xperia Z I tried it on (where it doesn't work correctly) and the Samsung Galaxy S4 I tried it on are running Android 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody see any obvious flaw in that code?

You are assuming that `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` has been broadcast, reflecting the new charging status, before whatever broadcast you are listening to ("plugged in/plugged out events") has been broadcast. I am not aware that this is a requirement. If the device sends its "plugged in/plugged out events" before `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, your code will be seeing the *last* `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, before the "plugged in/plugged out event".

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have:

```
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
```

in a try block and then when you log your output it is outside of the try block:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Battery charging " + isCharging , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Try putting your toast in your try block or expand the scope of isCharging:

```
public boolean isCharging;

public void method()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
    }catch(Exception e){...}
    Toast.makeText(context, "Battery charging " + isCharging , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is a rough copy and paste job, the toast is actually within the try block. I'll change it.